# Search for a local html file by name

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a folder of 200 academic journal articles that are saved as individual html files. I want to write a Python program, where the user is asked to input the file name, and the file will open so that it can be processed with beautiful soup. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question appropriately

Comment: You're expected to have tried something. SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.x, this could be done as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

filename = raw_input('Please enter filename: ')

with open(filename) as f_input:
    html = f_input.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print soup
```